# what does (uint8_t*)&recvLen) mean?

Tags: arduino

i am working on [this](https://codebender.cc/sketch:140599#(RFM)%20Send.ino) code.

and at this function

```
void rfmRead()
{
 static const uint8_t recvLenMax = 5;
 static uint8_t recvLen = recvLenMax;
 static uint8_t recvBuf[recvLenMax];

 if (rfm23.recv(recvBuf, (uint8_t*)&recvLen))
 {
    rfmSend();

 //     Serial.println((char*)recvBuf);
 }
}
```

I don't understand what

```
(uint8_t*)&recvLen)
```

mean or work?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the `recv` the variable `recvLen` as reference.

To pass a variable as reference you need to pass the function a pointer to the variable (that is what `&` is: an operator to extract the address of a variable).

The `(uint8_t*)` part is a cast: you are converting some kind of variable to another. In this case, since `recvLen` is a `uint8_t` itself (and so `&recvLen` is already a pointer to `uint8_t`) it is useless, but if `recvLen` was another kind of variable (e.g. a `signed char` or an `int`) you needed it since the function was expecting that kind of variable.